# How to add new data to FlatList. ( React-Native )

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I Used this method to add new data to FlatList

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState([/* Data */])

<FlatList
  data = {message}
  renderItem = {renderItem}
  keyExtractor = {keyExtractor}
/>

 setMessage((pre) => [/* new data */, ...pre])
```

When I add new data to it, It render all element in list. which kill application performance.

It was realtime application. Let say it has 20 element.So it render expensive element every time.When adding or deleting data.
I am not expert init. 
There is something call [extradata](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/485475ab3ef518642e60e80f930f1f862890f338/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js#L253).

Answer (score 0):

**FlatList is prop-driven.** Like all React components, when props change - the component will re-render() itself. FlatList is working exactly as it's designed.

FlatList rendering can be optimized:

- initialNumToRender
- getItemLayout()
- renderItem()
- shouldComponentUpdate() for components used in renderItem()

Tweak the components used in **renderItem()** to only render when absolutely necessary via lifecycle methods like **shouldComponentUpdate()**.

If you want better FlatList performance, you'll need to to adjust per your specific use case. https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe you can create a function like this: **

```
addData() {
        var b = { text: 'data' };
        usestates.push(b)
    }
```